# Why my website giving "The site ahead contains harmful programs" error?

Tags: google-chrome, malware, wordpress, malware-detection

My site is: [hints.steptoinstall.com](http://hints.steptoinstall.com/). It's build using Wordpress.

My lastest Post is: [PHP – Current Year for Copyright](http://hints.steptoinstall.com/php-current-year-for-copyright-footer.html), after making this post for the last 5 days I'm getting **The site ahead contains harmful programs** problem.

Because of this I'm getting low traffic.

How do I resolve this issue?

But main site working fine. [Step To Install](http://www.steptoinstall.com)

[image]

Comment: If you are seeing ` "Warning: Suspected Phishing Site Ahead!"` then it is one of your extensions causing this fake alert page http://chromepeeps.blogspot.in/2017/06/chrome-new-tab-suspected-site.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Why is my website giving a "The site ahead contains harmful programs" error?

This is a warning from Chrome:

> Google Chrome warns you if the site you're trying to visit is suspected of phishing or malware, using Google’s Safe Browsing technology. Phishing & malware alerts.

You site has been infected with "Phishing" software.

---

#### So what are the harmful programs or URLs?

You can analyse the page with [Redleg's File Viewer](http://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/).

[Analysing](http://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/?tgt=http%3A%2F%2Fhints.steptoinstall.com%2Fphp-current-year-for-copyright-footer.html&ref_sel=GSP2&ua_sel=chr&fs=1) your page returns the following results:

> Note! It looks like your domain is currently flagged by Google. You can verify the current status by checking the [Diagnostic Page](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://hints.steptoinstall.com/php-current-year-for-copyright-footer.html). If your site is flagged once you clean it up you must [request a malware review](http://aw-snap.info/articles/request-review.php) to have the warning removed.
>
> Suspicious URLs found in:
> http://hints.steptoinstall.com/php-current-year-for-copyright-footer.html
>
> 1. http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm?pid=663232&bid=1653778
> 2. http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm?pid=663232&bid=1655600
>
> Note: The URL(s) listed above have been found in the page you are
> checking. While the URL(s) are not currently flagged as suspicious by
> Google they have returned malicious content, unwanted software, and/or
> caused problems recently and should be investigated. Do they belong in
> your page?

---

#### Diagnostic page for hints.steptoinstall.com

> What is the current listing status for hints.steptoinstall.com?
>
> - Site is listed as suspicious - visiting this web site may harm your computer.
>
> What happened when Google visited this site?
>
> - Of the 10 pages we tested on the site over the past 90 days, 9 page(s) resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed
>   without user consent. The last time Google visited this site was on
>   2015-07-21, and the last time suspicious content was found on this
>   site was on 2015-07-21.
> - This site was hosted on 1 network(s) including AS26496 (26496-GO-DADDY-COM-LLC).
>
> Has this site acted as an intermediary resulting in further
> distribution of malware?
>
> - Over the past 90 days, hints.steptoinstall.com did not appear to function as an intermediary for the infection of any sites.
>
> Has this site hosted malware?
>
> - No, this site has not hosted malicious software over the past 90 days.
>
> How did this happen?
>
> - In some cases, third parties can add malicious code to legitimate sites, which would cause us to show the warning message.

Source [Safe Browsing Diagnostic page for hints.steptoinstall.com](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=bidvertiser.com)

---

#### What is Redleg's File Viewer?

> Free online tool to scan a website for malware, malicious redirects, malicious scripts and other bad stuff.

---

#### Phishing & malware alerts

> Google Chrome warns you if the site you're trying to visit is
> suspected of phishing or malware, using Google’s Safe Browsing
> technology. Phishing & malware alerts
>
> When phishing and malware detection is turned on you may see the
> following messages:
>
> - The Website Ahead Contains Malware! - The site you're trying to visit may install malware on your computer.
> - Danger: Malware Ahead! - The web page you're trying to visit may have malware.
> - Reported Phishing Website Ahead! - The site you’re trying to visit is suspected of being a phishing site.
> - The site ahead contains harmful programs - The site you're trying to visit may try to trick you into installing programs that harm your
>   browsing experience.
>
> Turn off phishing & malware warnings The following steps will turn of
> phishing and malware warnings, as well as download warnings.
>
> 1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu Chrome menu.
> 2. Select Settings.
> 3. Click Show advanced settings.
> 4. Under "Privacy," uncheck the box "Enable phishing and malware protection."

Source [Phishing & malware alerts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?hl=en)

Comment: I removed those and checked one more time. still same problem. in ' view Page Source ', there is no link to bidvertiser. :(

Comment: @KarSho I've updated the answer to include the Google analysis of **your** site. "Of the 10 pages we tested on the site over the past 90 days, 9 page(s) resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed without user consent. The last time Google visited this site was on 2015-07-21, and the last time suspicious content was found on this site was on 2015-07-21."

Comment: @KarSho "If your site is flagged once you clean it up you must [request a malware review](http://aw-snap.info/articles/request-review.php) to have the warning removed."

Comment: @KarSho You need to remove it from **every** page of your and then ask for a google review.